# CUDA processing image

Tags: c++, performance, cuda, parallel-processing

Thanks for reading my thread.

Here is what I want to do:

- I have many images on harddrive, say 100000 of them. Mostly they are 512X512 in size.
- I'd like to load one by one, and calculate the statistics, say mean intensity, variance, min, max and etc, of each single image.

I am wondering, can I use **CUDA** to accelerate the process here? Is it going to be faster then CPU processing?

I am brand new to **CUDA**, but I am thinking of using C++ project to do image file I/O (**libtiff**, for example), then using **CUDA** to do the calculation. In general, what would be the reasonable/fastest/quasi-fastest way to implement this project?

Any comment is higjhly appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Today date, it's not sure that taking GPU for that type of algorithm is going to be faster than on CPU. Reduction/finding algorithm is not really designed for GPU, if you can work with AVX + openMP you can probably have the same perfomance or maybe just a factor 2-3x (which is pretty good) but the time to code it in CUDA to get performance should take you some time (and even more if you are new to CUDA). I would rather recommend you to code it in C++. You can look for thrust in CUDA, math lib

Comment: So if I go for GPU, what do you think is the best structure for this project? Really appreciate your opinion.

Comment: I think learning CUDA is a real good thing but C++ should be better for your problem, in my point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People are right , but I will tell you go ahead and do it . Doing such operations on images is PERFECT  to understand CUDA and parallel programming , though not quite efficient as a multithreaded CPU.

My advice use
1- use a single thread to the do the operations and time each operation.
2- then use OpenMP to do the operations on the CPU ( using 2 , 4  and more threads , depending on the number of cores you have.
3- Try to program that in Cuda, you will learn a lot of parallel programing primitives in the process ( parallel reduce for the min , and mean operation )

later on when you are going to have more complex stuff like Histograms , deformable registration or smoothing operation you will start to appreciate the parallel programing speed.

HINT : the IO operations like reading images will have same code in all programs.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that having CUDA will not help you because:
1. Image data must be transferred to Graphics Controller.
2. Results must be transferred from Graphics Controller to CPU.

Data paths from the GPU to the CPU are not optimized for speed, since most of the traffic is from CPU to GPU.

You would get better performance by optimizing your operations for Data Cache.  Search the web for "C++ Data Cache Optimization".

Also search for "loop unrolling" and "double buffer read".

I predict your bottleneck is not in the image analysis of the data, but reading the data into memory.

Also look at distributing computation among CPU cores.  For example, Core 1 works on the odd numbered images and Core 2 works on the even numbered images.

Comment: "Data paths from the GPU to the CPU are not optimized for speed, since most of the traffic is from CPU to GPU." That's just incorrect.  PCIE speed is the same in both directions.  Also, in this use case the amount of data you are returning to the CPU is a few bytes, so the cost of moving results back is basically zero.  If you overlap the DMA from the CPU to the GPU with computation using cudaMemcopyAsync you can often get significant speedups for these types of image processing queries.  Check out the NPP library which has all of the image processing operations you would need.

Answer (score 0):

CUDA will probably not help you very much (assuming such cheap statistical evaluations) since host-to-device copy instructions are quite expensive. If you want to try it: Take a look at parallel reduction for your tasks.
I would first implement a simple CPU-threaded version and check performance. Just use one thread to fill a buffer with files (input) and a few workers (depends on the configuration of your machine) to to the calculations.

Comment: You mean one thread filling the buffer the other threads launching GPU to do calculation? The stats could be much harder, I was just throwing some example I can think of for now.

Comment: As Thomas also suggested, use a CPU-threaded version. CUDA will probably not help you very much, since file I/O will be the biggest bottleneck. CUDA shines if you can copy data from host memory to device memory and do some pretty expensive and well parallelizable tasks without host-device copy operations in between. For your task, i think this ist not the case.